# Django en Servidor Virtual con SO Ubuntu server, cómo puedo ver la webapp?

Tags: django, ubuntu-server

Tengo una maquina virtual (virtualbox) con Ubuntu server(sin interfaz gráfica).
Estoy desarrollando una webapp con python y Django
Cuando subo el entorno de desarrollo ( `$ python manage.py runserver`) me dice que puedo ver la webapp en http://127.0.0.1:8000

¿Cómo hago para verlo desde el equipo windows o desde la red a la cual está conectada? ya lo intenté con su dirección y puerto (http://192.168.1.11:8000) y me dice "La página 192.168.1.11 ha rechazado la conexión".

Nota: la máquina virtual ya está en mi red, tiene ip 192.168.1.11, ya logré conectarme al servidor de base de datos, y responde el ping; es decir, que ya está en la red.

Comment: Por un lado, esta pregunta parece *off-topic*. Por otro lado, si tu aplicación se ejecuta en la VM, en puerto `8000`, debes asegurarte que tienes la regla de permitir conexiones a dicho puerto en la configuración del Firewall de tu VM, siendo un servidor Ubuntu, tendrás que usar `iptables` muy probablemente. Saludos

Comment: Conoces algún link donde pueda encontrar el proceso para habilitar  conexiones desde la misma red (para hacer las pruebas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes ver la página porque iniciaste el servidor en el loopback de la máquina virtual. No en las otras interfaces de red.

Puedes habilitar a Django para que "escuche" en todas las interfaces así.

`$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`

Comment: Añadir que debe permitir el acceso al puerto 8000 en el firewall del servidor Ubuntu

Comment: Tambien debo agregar que se debe editar el archivo settings.py  en el parametro ```ALLOWED_HOSTS=['<con la ip de la Maquina virtual>',] ```o con ```ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*',]``` para que permita todas

Comment: Para debugeo y desarrollo `ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']`. Cuando este en producttion cambialo al nombre de dominio del sitio.