# Servidor web django > acceso red local

Tags: android, python-3.x, django, localhost

**Hola!**

soy programador principiante y estoy probando organizar un buen html responsive, para eso, utilizo: `PYTHON` y `DJANGO`. luego de crear un Témplate decente en mi pc windows abro el servidor local co n django`python manage.py runserver`, al cual puedo acceder normalmente desde mi pc  `"localhost:8000`.
El error ocurre cuando intento acceder desde dispositivos móviles dentro de mi red wifi local.
No hay forma de acceder, estoy poniendo la ip(`ipv4`) correcta, también su respectivo puerto.

o estoy abriendo mal el servidor desde `django`(lo dudo porque puedo ingresar normalmente desde mi pc) o mi móvil tiene un error, o estoy accediendo mal, o necesito algún otro programa para gestionar mi servidor web (como apache por ejemplo)?

**alguien puede ayudarme? **

**Agradezco cualquier ayuda! muchísimas gracias**

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/493884/django-en-servidor-virtual-con-so-ubuntu-server-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-ver-la-webapp/493976#493976 Necesitas que django escuche en todas las interfaces de la pc.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la variable **ALLOWED_HOSTS** en tus settings.py, por defecto Django sólo sirve hacia *localhost*

Si quieres servir a cualquier host debes definirla como:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

OJO: Esto es recomendable sólo para desarrollo

Además si su usas el servidor de desarrollo *runserver* debes especificar que puede ser consultado sin importar su IP (*0.0.0.0*)

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!  me sirvio.

✔️✔️✔️✔️SOLUCIONADO✔️✔️✔️✔️